# requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think my code is clean and simple , but i got this error :

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://support
.google.com/
```

When trying to run it .

I don't know why actually i tried too many things

when i change

```
fuzing_website_response = requests.get(f'http://{i}.{take_input}/')
```

to

```
fuzing_website_response = requests.get(f'http://{take_input}/{i}')
```

and run it and with valid URL input _ > it will give me the responses status_code successfully .

But the other code which try to enumerate subdomains given me the provided error even when http://support.google.com
is a valid url

Detailed response with the reason of the problem will be appreciated.

Script code :

```
take_input = input('Enter the website > ')
take_file = open('list.txt','r')


for i in take_file:
    fuzing_website_response = requests.get(f'http://{i}.{take_input}/')
    print (f'{take_input}/{i} ---> {fuzing_website_response.status_code}')
```

Comment: It seems the string you pass as an url has newline character in it. I believe you can mitigate this by _stripping_ `i`, `i = i.strip()`.

Comment: In general, why don’t you simply print the URL before you try to use it - then you can see if it looks strange.

Comment: Can u re write the code for me , i didn't understand .. sorry but i'm noob/beginner in python

Answer (score 13):

This is actually something with the urllib3 library because requests parses the url with urllib3,  urllib3's parser isn't percent-encoding characters within the userinfo section of the URL, just upgrade your urllib3 it will work.

How to upgrade or install ?

```
python -m pip install --upgrade urllib3
```

---

```
pip install urllib3
```

---

from github repository:

```
git clone git://github.com/urllib3/urllib3.git
cd urllib3
python setup.py install
```