# requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse error even after upgrading urllib3

Tags: python, image, selenium, web-scraping

I created a program that accepts input from user and scrape images from google images using selenium
by clicking on the images and then extracting their source code and then using `requests.get(sourcecode).content` convert image to binary which is then downloaded into the actual image using "writebinary" mode in `open()` function. Here is the code:

```
import requests


import random

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
PATH=r"C:\Users\Binoy\Desktop\Techwiz\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)

i=0
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import time
ac=str(random.randint(1,20))
b=str(random.randint(20,38))
y=Tk()
def find_file():
    aaa=filedialog.askdirectory()
    return aaa
def create_folder():
    ad=find_file()
    global ac
    global b
    ads=os.path.join(ad,f"Img{ac}{b}")
    os.mkdir(ads)
    return ads


defe=Entry(bg="white")
defe.grid(row=2,column=2)
adj=Label(text="Enter the name of the photo(s) you want to download :")
adj.grid(row=2,column=1)
ack=Label(text="How many photos you want to download?")
ack.grid(row=3,column=1)
dee=Entry(bg="white")
dee.grid(row=3,column=2)


        



def download_images():
    

    defei=defe.get()
    deee=int(dee.get())
    aadgc=[]
    play=True   
    asd=create_folder()
    bararara=f"https://www.google.co.in/search?q={defei}&source=lnms&tbm=isch&start=0"
    it=0
    driver.get(bararara)
    abc=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rg_i.Q4LuWd")
        
    for source in abc:
        r=random.randint(0,100) 
        ra=random.randint(0,1000) 
        source.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        image_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tvh9oe.BIB1wf .eHAdSb>img").get_attribute("src")
        raa=asd+"\\"+str(r)+str(ra)+".png"
        image_link=image_link.strip()
        if "http" not in image_link:
            image_link="http://"+image_link
        binary=requests.get(image_link).content      
        with open(raa,"wb") as saaho:
            saaho.write(binary)
            saaho.close()
        global i
        i+=1
        if i==int(deee):
            break 
    
    asd=asd.replace("/","\\")
    os.system(f"explorer \"{asd}\"") 
aadg=Button(y,bg="red",text="Download!",command=lambda:download_images(),activebackground="dark red",activeforeground="grey")
aadg.grid(row=4,column=1)
y.mainloop()      
aadg=Button(y,bg="red",text="Download!",command=lambda:download_images(),activebackground="dark red",activeforeground="grey")
aadg.grid(row=4,column=1)
y.mainloop()
```

While running,it worked fine with most images and downloaded them,but for some it would raise this exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 382, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py", line 392, in parse_url 
    return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Binoy\Desktop\Techwiz\Python\Python Projects\google_photo_generator.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    aadg=Button(y,bg="red",text="Download!",command=lambda:download_images(),activebackground="dark red",activeforeground="grey")
  File "c:\Users\Binoy\Desktop\Techwiz\Python\Python Projects\google_photo_generator.py", line 71, in download_images
    binary=requests.get(image_link).content
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request       
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\Binoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 384, in prepare_url
    raise InvalidURL(*e.args)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Then I tried updating `urllib3` library according to [requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444298/requests-exceptions-invalidurl-failed-to-parse)
but it is still raising the error.

Edit 1:
I found out that if I increase the time in line 65(time.sleep(1)) to a five seconds,the error doesn't come. I think that some images took time to load and so were replaced by a dummy/alternative pic[in this case the first frame of the gif] which had  a faulty url.
I thank everyone who tried to solve our problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check getting the variable image_link. Failed to parse: http://data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/ and etc... - this error describe prompt to us that something wrong with our url

Comment: Thanks for trying to help,but we did this already and found no issues on the url